# How to check if a variable contains a type or a list of types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I'd like to pass a type or a list of types as an argument to a function. But within the function I need to distinguish between the type and the list of types. Roughly explained I need some kind of branching like this:

```
if //someVar is a type//:
    ....
elif isinstance(someVar, list):
    for t in list:
        if //t is a type//:
            ....
        else:
            print("ERROR")
else
    print("ERROR")
```

Types can either be some "primitive" like *int* or *str* but also tuples or classes as well.

The question: How can I correctly and efficiently distinguish between types and list of types?

Comment: Could you explain the broader context of what you're trying to do. Have you looked into e.g. `isinstance`/`issubclass`?

Comment: you need to explicitly check for `list`s? Also, what *doesn't* qualify as a type for you?

Comment: For clarification: My intention is to pass type information to a type verification method. I want to give the user some kind of freedom how to specify type constraints passed to this method. Therefor I'd like to allow him to either specify a single type or a list of types (and eventually some other options in the future). Therefor the information provided would be stored in a single variable. In consequence I need some kind of branching within the code in order to correctly work with the information provided by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide a `tuple` to `isinstance` containing the types you think are appropriate as "primitive". For lists you'll just pass a `list`.

If you need to handle *"classes as well"* you'll need to explicitly add those classes in the tuple since there is no `ClassType` in Python (at least in Python `3`, in Python `2` old-style classes had a common type).

So, given an example class `Bar`, here's how you would allow `str`, `int`s, `tuple`s and `Bar` as "primitive" while further checking for lists:

```
class Bar: pass

def foo(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, (int, str, tuple, Bar)):
        print("type str or int or tuple or Bar")
    elif isinstance(arg, list):
        print("a list")
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Function `foo` now makes these distinctions for you:

```
>>> foo(1)
type str or int or tuple or Bar
>>> foo([1])
a list
>>> foo(Bar())
type str or int or tuple or Bar
>>> foo(foo)
Error
```

further branching in the `elif` clause for `list`s is similarly performed.

Comment: No common type for classes ... That's quite inconvenient. Some piece of code can not explicitly check against all classes that exist. Please see the additional information provided above as a comment to my question. Have you any idea how to achieve this? I need to distinguish between an object that represents a type (f.e. a list) and an instance of that type (a list of f.e. types) explicitely.

Comment: @RegisMay what arg would the user supply? Do the inputs: `foo(list)`, `foo(int)` belong in the "single" `type` category and `foo([int, str, tuple])` belong in the `list` of `type`s category?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Jim gave the right hint: I can pass tuples or single values to isinstance(). So I can achieve exactly what I want. I can skip branching completely as this is done by isinstance() itself! Thank you for your answer, Jim!

Comment: @RegisMay I'm glad this helped you out, good luck with your project :-)